# SVG hover with transition

Tags: jquery, css, svg

i recently started to learn SVG. I tried to make a circle with some text inside.
here is my code :

```
<div class="main_circle">
        <a href="#">
            <svg height="392" width="392" id="svg_circle">

                <circle cx="196" cy="196" r="194" class="circle1" id="circle1"/>

                <text x = "70" y = "100" font-size = "30" fill="#fff"> 
                    <tspan font-family = "'Ubuntu', sans-serif" font-weight = "100">
                        some text
                    </tspan>
              Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
            </svg>
         </a> 

         <script>
             $( "#svg_circle" ).hover(function() {
                    $("#circle1").attr({r:"150"});
             });


             $( "#svg_circle" ).mouseleave(function() {
                    $("#circle1").attr({r:"194"});
             });
         </script>

    </div>
```

i would like the circle to be smaller when i hover it and the text to disappear, if it possible. i achieved to make it smaller but i would like to put transition to look nice. if anyone can help i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To animate the text's opacity and position, group the `circle` and the `text` using the `g` tag. Attach a `:hover` event to the group, animate `#text`'s `fill-opacity` from `1` to `0` and `transform: translate(0, -100px)` to move to `100px` above.

And for animating the `r` attribute of the `cirlce` you could make use of the `animate` tag and start the animation on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events through JavaScript.

```js
var shape = document.getElementById('shape');
shape.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  document.getElementById('shrink').beginElement();
});
shape.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  document.getElementById('grow').beginElement();
});
```

```css
#shape #text {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#shape:hover #text {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main_circle">
  <svg height="392" width="392" id="svg_circle">
    <g id="shape">
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <circle cx="196" cy="196" r="194" class="circle" id="circle" />
        <animate id="shrink" xlink:href="#circle" attributeType="XML" attributeName="r" from="194" to="150" dur="0.5s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />
        <animate id="grow" xlink:href="#circle" attributeType="XML" attributeName="r" from="150" to="194" dur="0.5s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />
        <text id="text" font-family="'Ubuntu', sans-serif" opacity="1" font-weight="100" x="196" y="196" text-anchor="middle" font-size="30" fill="#fff">Some text</text>
      </a>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer above.

i notice that if i mouseover "some text" then zoom out again. is there any way to resolve this?

also is it possible to move the position of the text when hover?